# Assign the value from a iframe element to a variable with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, openlayers-3, onload

First place, sorry for a newbie question.
Well, I' am trying to acess a `iframe` element and assign the value from a `div` to a variable using `javascript`.

Originally, the `html` has no `iframe`. It is created with a click event function in `Openlayers3`, which creates a `url` and assign it to the `iframe` source.

To better explain, here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var map = new ol.Map(); // create some map.
 var a = [...]; // array with 'n' elements, each with a source.
 map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '';
  var b = [];
  for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    var url = a[i].getSource().getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
        evt.coordinate, someresolution, "EPSG:...", {'INFO_FORMAT':'text/html'}
    );
    if(url){
      document.getElementById('info').innerHTML='<iframe id="frame" seamless src="'+url+'"></iframe>';
    }
    document.getElementById('frame').onload = function(){f()};
    function f(){
     return document.getElementById('frame').contentWindow.document.getElementById('t').innerHTML;
    }
    b[i] = f();
  }
 });
});
```

With this code I can't store the content of the `div` `t` in the variable `b`.

I did some test with the `alert` function and actually the value of the `div` was printed on my screen, but it can't assing it to `b`. Oddly, in these test the value from the first iteration was skiped.

Could someone please help me on these issue?

Comment: Where is `n` defined?

Comment: It makes no sense to have a `return` statement in the `onload` callback. It runs asynchronously. `b[i] = f()` won't do anything useful, because it's running before the iframe is loaded.